# How to calculate elevation gain for a route not recommended (by Google) for cycling

Tags: road-bike, navigation

I have a need to figure out elevation gain on a (United States) freeway (to compare options) to plan a cycling route. Google will NOT allow me to drag the points into the freeway route if cycling is the transportation method. If I switch it to a driving route, Google will not give elevation gain stats.

It appears that if a route is not recommended for cycling, Google will not let you route it (which I realize could be hazardous otherwise). IMO, it should only give a warning and let users make their desired route.

Anyhow, is there a way out there to get elevation gain stats on road/routes not recommended for cycling?

After some thought I feel strongly that this question is in the correct context here. True it’s a question also about software, but I doubt the software user base has as much to offer it as cyclists do.

Whether or not it’s legal or safe is a bit irrelevant. Google’s safety and legal limitations are just examples of why I might need such a feature. And we know that software, the law, and road and highway planning aren’t perfect. For the purpose of just finding out if such a feature exists somewhere on this planet, we’ll say I’m using my best judgements about safety, and would not do something I felt was a risk for myself or others. Safety is another primary goal in using our own judgement for considering all possible routes. The law may in some cases be wrong, or many not regard changing conditions such as weather or road construction, and direct us through a *more* dangerous route. Also, say we’re out on the road and there’s some sort of emergency; elevation may become a critical consideration in finding the best way home.

Comment: Your title says "not recommended" for cycling, but then you mention a freeway. Is it even legal to cycle there? I no longer use Google maps for route planning but (local errors aside) have always been able to drag onto unwise roads

Comment: Also, Google maps is rubbish for elevation.  This [old question of mine](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/47089/7309) discusses alternatives.  My [own answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/50984/7309), while a little dated, may be of some use.

Comment: @chrish, it must be a new ‘feature’, I know it would not let me do it last summer in Colorado. AFAIK it’s legal to cycle on a freeway if there are no other road options in your direction. I’ve biked many miles on freeways, and never been pulled over or told otherwise.

Comment: I don't know the law where you are, and most of the US freeways I've driven were around LA where it would be suicide.  Here our motorways (the nearest equivalent) are definitely illegal for cycling and Google, Strava and Komoot won't let me route on them.  The latter two use openstreetmap data unlike google, so may give you an alternative.

Comment: The obvious answer is to put Google maps in 'Driving' mode when researching alternate routes which include roads where cycling is not allowed. The app will no longer suggest the optimum routes for cycling or course, so you'll have to micromanage the route with waypoints to make sure it goes where you want it to.

Comment: Re 'Google will not let you route it, which is garbage ...' Think of this from the point if view of Google, they don't want lawsuits because their app routed cyclists onto roads where it is illegal and dangerous to ride.

Comment: @Agenti, when you put Google Maps in driving mode it does not give elevation gain statistics.

Comment: @Swift, huh?! I’m specifically asking about how to route for cycling.

Comment: In parts of the US it is permitted to cycle on an interstate or other freeway when there is no other reasonable route and when traffic and road conditions are acceptable.  Usually such routes are clearly identified with signs  saying "Bicycles permitted" or some such.

Comment: If you indicate a specific stretch that's definitely legal to ride but not routable by Google, I'll test some other tools against it.  Google's bike route planning is pretty much the most basic option there is, so something else might be more suitable

Comment: @Chris, what would you test it against? You’re suggesting there’s something better, so what is it?

Comment: I updated the title of the question to be more clear what I’m asking.

Comment: The URL ridewithgps.com route planner can be set to driving mode which will route on freeways/interstate and show elevation. It appears to use Google mapping service.

Comment: @Thanks! If you post that as an answer, I’ll be able to upvote/select it.

Comment: Carry a barometer with you!  https://www.beauchampantiques.com/app/uploads/2015/01/A26291.jpg

Comment: Consider that you're asking about software, which has only a slight connection with bicycles.  I'd suggest that https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is a better home for this question.

Comment: @Daniel, a barometer will not help for planning a route beforehand. Also, that measures atmospheric pressure, not elevation.

Comment: @BBaysinger - Sure it will help.  Just walk to several points along the route and take the pressure.  Then figure that pressure changes by about a half a pound per 1000 feet.  Then figure that an inch change in the mercury level is about a half a pound as well.

Comment: @Daniel, I’m making plans before I reach the route.

Comment: There are so many mapping and planning softwares available. Google is only on of any and certainly not the best one, esecially not for unpaved roads and off road in my country.

Comment: I mainly use Komoot and Strava, but can't route down illegal routes here. There's also RideWithGPS, which uses different routing algorithms depending on which base map you select.   Then there's ViaMichelin which I've found useful in France and a whole host of others. Also, with a specific stretch in mind, I can log in to OpensStreetMap as an editor and inspect the data

Comment: @P.BarneyRWGPS uses Google's routing if you're displaying Google's maps in it. I don't use it often but when I do, I use OSM, and that uses a different routing engine (there are few for OSM, and I'm not sure which)

Comment: @BBaysinger - Hey!  I was funnin' you!!

Comment: Though, seriously, I will point out that you can buy a topographical map and figure out the elevations the old-fashioned way.

Comment: Well yeah... But that’s prone to error, and possibly maddening when comparing many many routes regularly.

Comment: Minor improvement - could you indicate what country you're asking about?  The words Freeway / Motorway / Highway have subtly-different meanings between countries.  ie, for me its illegal to cycle on a Motorway, but a State Highway is fine.  We don't have Freeways, and this might be leading to confusion.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was your intention, but the answers and comments on this question have evolved into service recommendations, which are off topic on this site. Therefore, I have closed it. If you're not looking for a service, please reword your question to indicate more clearly what you are looking for and it will be automatically flagged for reopening. Alternatively, you can ask your question in [the Velodrome](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome) where the guidelines are much more open.

Comment: @jimchristie Was is a service here?

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend https://brouter.de/brouter-web for bicycle route planning. It also calculates elevation gain/loss and tries to avoid elevation changes.

Keep in mind that elevation data can be inaccurate since it’s usually using Digital Elevation Models which are based on satellite data. For example it might miss things like bridges entirely and display a huge elevation gain/loss for crossing a gorge. See https://brouter.de/brouter/elevation.html

Comment: Does it allow you to route along roads marked as unsuitable though?

Comment: @ChrisH: You can completely customize the criteria/rules, so yes.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to get an estimate (rough, but quite possibly better than Google's) using [Strava route builder](https://www.strava.com/routes/new) in **manual mode**.  I've checked against a local motorway (where cycling is illegal and would be very dangerous) and figures are not unreasonable.  You'll need a (free) login. What you need to do:

- without enabling manual mode, click on your start point
- click on the normal road at the freeway junction
- adjust the route to the freeway as you like
- enable manual mode and click OK to the warning
- click points on the freeway, ending where you want to leave it.  The route won't follow the road, so curves may need a few points to define them properly
- turn manual mode back off and click on your destination
- adjust the route from the freeway to the destination